# How to track incoming traffic from a certain link?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, conversion-tracking

I have a software that has a free and a commercial (pro) version. It can be installed on a webserver similar to WordPress. The free version has a link in the admin area telling the user to upgrade to the pro version.

I'd like to track how many sales this link generates.

I was wondering if this is possible with Google analytics or GTM. For example adding a special class to that link and create a conversion tracking like this:

Link click (from the user's website) => Product landing page => Checkout/payment => Thank you page

Is something like this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use UTM parameters. They are campaign parameters to add in querystring to the URLs so you can track custom Campaigns in Google Analytics. Example:

```
http://yoursite.com/yoururl/?utm_source=mysite&utm_medium=link_from_fre_version
```

You can use this tool online. Filling out the fields in the form the full campaign URL will be generated for you:

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/